# How to append the string to textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to append the given string to the textarea i have, i want to append the text in the way it should look like someone typing on the texture,because i have the voice playing in the background for 6 seconds which which says the same thing to be written.

```
<textarea id='typeable' style='font-size:18px;background:#F8E71C'></textarea>    

<script>
    function addText(event) {
        document.getElementById("typeable").value += "Hello welcome to the new world of javascript"
    }
    </script>
```

how can i do this

Comment: You have your answer right there?
Only change the "alltext" to id of textarea "typeable"

Comment: @user3328306 _"it should look like someone typing"_

Comment: I think the OP wants the text to be "written" to the textarea character to character, like a human would.

Comment: Make a sequence when you wait time before each text adding ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+typewriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the **number of characters** in the sentence, and then calculate the **time for each char** by dividing the total time with the no. of characters and then call the time Interval and run it until all the characters are printed.

Still you can decide the time taken to print each character and modify it as per your need. Please note that the time is taken in milliseconds.

```js
var chars = "Hello welcome to the new world of javascript".split("");
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var total_time=6000;
var index = 0;
var time_per_char = total_time/chars.length;
var t = setInterval(function(){
 textarea.value += chars[index];
  index++;
  if (index === chars.length){
   clearInterval(t);
  }
},time_per_char);
```

```html
<textarea style="width:100%;background:#E1ECF4">

</textarea>
```

Comment: At the end its saying undefined undefined. how to remove that undefined

Comment: It does not print undefined. The timer is cleared once all the characters are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Code is attached below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function appendText() {
 document.getElementById("typeable").value= document.getElementById("typeable").value + "Hello welcome to the new world of javascript";
}

</script>
<body onload="appendText()">
<textarea id='typeable' style='font-size:18px;background:#F8E71C'></textarea>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asks for: _"it should look like someone typing"_