# Trying to find an easier way to make an jQuery "writing" animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

So my own solution to this is. However, this would become tedious if the text is too long.

```js
var typeThis = "blablablablabla:";
var displayText = "";

function type(fullString, typedSoFar) {
  if (fullString.length != typedSoFar.length) {
    typedSoFar = fullString.substring(0, typedSoFar.length + 1);
    document.getElementById(".animatedTyping").innerText = typedSoFar;
    setTimeout(function() {
      type(fullString, typedSoFar)
    }, 100);
  }
}

document.getElementById(".animatedTyping").innerHtml = typeThis;
var element = document.createElement('span');
element.innerHTML = typeThis;
typeThis = element.textContent;
type(typeThis, displayText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><span class="animatedTyping"></span></h2>
```

Comment: Please check ]this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38222236/3863146) also where js has been used to have a typing effect which works for any sentence length.

Comment: Can I suggest you rollback your edit so the question will make sense to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery feels a bit overkill.  You could use plain javascript to achieve the same effect.  Simply start with your full string, then in a loop take a substring of it and set a timeout to run the function again until the whole string is typed. To escape HTML encoded data you can create a new element add your text as HTML and then pull the text out (credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/1173776) -

```js
var typeThis = "My typing speed is &lt; fast.";
var displayText = "";

function type(fullString, typedSoFar) {
  if (fullString.length != typedSoFar.length) {
    typedSoFar = fullString.substring(0, typedSoFar.length + 1);
    document.getElementById("animatedTyping").innerText = typedSoFar;
    setTimeout(function() {
      type(fullString, typedSoFar)
    }, 100);
  }
}

document.getElementById("animatedTyping").innerHtml = typeThis;
var element = document.createElement('span');
element.innerHTML = typeThis;
typeThis = element.textContent;
type(typeThis, displayText);
```

```html
Watch me type -<span id="animatedTyping"></span>
```

Comment: Would this also work with symbols? e.g. &lt; and &frasl; ??? Would the computer be able to read those as individual characters?

Comment: @suonpera With typelt you can use this symbols, but if you want to use js you have to implement them extra I think

Comment: @suonpera [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) you can see how to do it without jquery

Comment: Thanks @theoretisch I've updated my answer to avoid jQuery

Comment: @suonpera In your code you're referencing your element by class whereas in my code I'm using the elements ID which in this case I would argue is the better approach if your text is being added to a specific element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Typelt**](http://macarthur.me/typeit/)

```js
$('.1').typeIt({
     strings: 'This is a simple string.',
     speed: 50
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.3.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="1"></span></p>
```

Comment: Great solution. But I looking for one that doesn't require a plugin